# write a two column file from two files using awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have two files of one column each

```
1
2
3
```

and

```
4
5
6
```

I want to write a unique file with both elements as

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

It should be really simple I think with awk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try `paste -d ' ' <file1> <file2>`. (Without `-d ' '` the delimiter would be tab.)

Answer (score 4):

`paste` works okay for the example given but it doesn't handle variable length lines very well. A nice little-know core-util `pr` provides a more flexible solution:

```
$ pr -mtw 4 file1 file2
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

A variable length example:

```
$ pr -mtw 22 file1 file2
10         4
200        5
300,000,00 6
```

---

And since you asked about `awk` here is one way:

```
$ awk '{a[FNR]=a[FNR]$0" "}END{for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)print a[i]}' file1 file2
1 4 
2 5 
3 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[FNR]=$0;next } { print a[FNR],$0 }' file{1,2}
```

#### Explanation:

- `NR==FNR` will ensure our first action statement runs for first file only.
- `a[FNR]=$0` with this we are inserting first file into array a indexed at line number
- Once first file is complete we move to second action
- Here we print each line of first file along with second file

Comment: Note: This would fail if the files are of different length or for more than two files.